Does Qt have limitations with Bluetooth Low Energy and Coded PHY enabled devices?
I am in the process of developing a long range BLE module where the client can use a QT developed piece of software to scan and connect to the device. Previously, we have used the same software to connect to BLE devices without coded PHY enabled, and the software is able to scan, identify, and connect to device.
With this new module, it seems that the QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent class is unable to find my device with Coded PHY enabled. If I do a scan with my NRF application on my phone I am able to see the device, and if I scan with the generic windows bluetooth scanner, it is also able to locate the device. I have a series of qdebug prints that show identified devices.
I am using a Nordic based bluetooth chip (NINA-B3) and once I set the following AT command: AT+UBTLECFG=29,4
the device is not found, however setting it to 29,0 allows the device to be located.

I have also tested this using the example BLE scanner project in QT on QT5 and QT6 versions which produces the same results.
Does QT have any limitations in regard to long range enabled devices? Or is this a library issue I am having? I built QT 5.15.15 and QT 6.5.3 from source. The module is about 30cm from my PC with an RSSI of -50 when scanned from my phone.
Thanks.

Have you checked that your PC running the QT application also supports LE Coded Phy and is configured accordingly?

@Risto yes it does. I am able to scan using the installed Bluetooth chip on my PC and windows is able to at least identify the device

and you are sure that the LE Coded Phy is used while scanning instead of the  default LE 1M PHY? I want to point out that support for the LE Coded PHY is optional.

@Risto From my peripheral device, yes I am sure. I've configured it as such via the AT command, and using the nRF app on my phone, I am able to scan, identify, and bond to the device (and select the preferred PHY connection method). The AT setting I have highlighted in the red box above states that it enables scanning and advertising. Setting 0 states "Scanning and advertising 1Mbps, extended advertising disabled.", and 4 is "Scanning and advertising 1Mbps, CODED secondary." which would mean that they both scan with 1Mbps setting as primary, and does not make sense that QT cannot see it.

and again, using windows native bluetooth scanner also displays the device in the "found" list.

and again, have you checked that LE Coded Phy is used in your setup? For example: Bluetooth HCI trace with Win10.  In general, asking service questions about a software library tends to be off-topic. My aim is to give you the opportunity to answer your question yourself. Personally, however, I wouldn't put too much faith in a company that intermixes incompatible technologies in a single software function/architecture.

@Risto fair enough - I misinterpreted your original question. Been doing some reading and found that I may need to enable native win32 bluetooth when compiling QT from source.

@Risto using windows bluetooth virtual sniffer, I am able to scan and identify the dev kit i have configured. QT support is quite bad as is. Really hard to get a response from them.

Although, I think there is more at play here, and I don't think compiling the win32 bluetooth version of QT will fix my issue. I've done some more digging with some sniffers and wireshark and have sent some questions to Nordic to look at.
